# Update dynamoDB gsi composite sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, composite-key, secondary-indexes, dynamodb-gsi

My dynamoDB table has a GSI which its sort key is composite key. This composite key looks like this: `#STATUS#CREATED_AT`. The status field can be changed during update action on item, but I noticed even if I change the `GSI_sk` in primary table, this field doesn't change at all.

e.g.

1. my `Item1` has a field `GSI_sk` with the value `OPEN#1234`
2. I update `Item1` which `GSI_sk` is changed to `CLOSED#1234`
3. The `GSI_sk` remained unchanged (still `OPEN#1234`) when I queried `Item1` again

How to update my item and also update the `GSI_sk` field?

Comment: It will change. It might take a short bit of time.

Comment: does consistent read option make sure I can get the latest change?

Comment: That was my mistake. I used the wrong field name when getting data. Confirm it's changed